# How to prevent snakemake from running an aggregate rule with no wildcards when expand results in an empty list of files?

Tags: snakemake

I'm working on a snakemake workflow that has some optional rules.  Those rules should only execute when optional metadata is present in a tab-delimited sample file.  Long story short, the raw sample data should be able to go through the first dozen or so rules, but later steps require the presence of replicate information which is time-consuming to gather, and can be aided by the output of the first dozen rules.

I know that I could (and do have) reparate `all` rules to run the separate portions of the workflow, but I'd *like* to have the `all` rule run as much as is possible.  If the metadata is absent, only run the first dozen rules.  If the metadata is present, run all rules.

What I've got pretty much works except: when the metadata is absent, one aggregate rule with no wildcards tried to run with no inputs.  Here is that rule:

```
rule combine_idr_peaks:
    input:
        expand(
            "results/idr/{dataset}/merged.idr.narrowPeak",
            dataset=DATASETS,
        ),
    output:
        temp("results/idr/merged.idr.narrowPeak"),
    conda:
        "../envs/bedtools_coreutils.yml"
    shell:
        """
        cat {input:q} | \
        sortBed | \
        mergeBed > {output:q}
        """
```

And when it tried to run that rule with the absent metadata, and with the `--printshellcmds` flag, the command looks like this:

```
cat  | sortBed | mergeBed > results/idr/merged.idr.narrowPeak
```

Obviously, the workflow hangs, because cat is waiting for input.

`DATASETS` is a variable that is populated at the top of the snakefile from the metadata, which is intentionally missing in my test.  It is a part of the metadata that is optional.

How can I tell snakemake that this rule should not execute if the input is empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to tell `snakemake` somewhere else, that it should not run this rule - `snakemake` does not offer the option of not running a rule solely based on an empty list of input files, as the command and output files could still hold relevance.

Assuming your `all` rule looks something like this:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        rules.combine_idr_peaks.output,
        <other input files>
```

How about including this input conditional on `DATASETS` being not empty:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        # First option
        rules.combine_idr_peaks.output if DATASETS else [],
        # second option
        rules.combine_idr_peaks.output if rules.combine_idr_peaks.input else [],
        <other input files>
```

With the first option, the file(s) from `rules.combine_idr_peaks.output` will not be a dependency of `rule all` if `DATASETS` is empty, and therefore the list of input files of your rule. The second option is the one I'd personally prefer which works the same way and instead of indirectly determining whether input files for the rule exists, it actually queries the rules `input` files.